# Running jar files from python leads to Initialization errors

Tags: java, python, command-line, jar, pycharm

I have a jar file, which runs as expected when passing certain command line arguments.
eg:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar -help
```

provides me the information I need.

Now we plan to migrate to a python environment. I take the jar and execute the following in PyCharm

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'MyJar.jar',' -help'])
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class testclient.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runners/model/InitializationError
```

Do i need to configure anything here? I expect the jar to show some results similar to the command line. Could anyone guide me here

Comment: have you created a runnable jar? can you check that.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the CLASSPATH environment variable is available to the process.

Comment: @karthikakinapelli, nope it is not a runnable jar,.

Comment: can you try making it to runnable jar and try

Comment: @tgdavies, extremely sorry, I am not able to get you. So when I exported the jar in eclipse, I gave a custom manifest file, with Class-Path pointing to lib directory with all jars. I believe that is not what you are referring to..

Comment: Are you referring to the Python path in environment variables?

Comment: @karthikakinapelli Actually here are multiple run configurations in this applicaition, and I dont want to limit the jar to just one configuration. Additionally, I created a custom manifest file to add libraries to the classpath

Comment: When you say `-jar` to the JVM, you are *ignoring* any classpath. It would seem that your jar does not contain some classes it needs, IOW you have not made a 'fat jar'. I'm not entirely sure why your jar is looking for junit classes, unless for some reason it still has something to do with testing. *Does* your app need junit classes? You shouldn't need anything to do with junit to *run* a jar.

Comment: yes my application is doing testing